# How can I zoom in the entire GitAhead GUI?

Tags: gitahead

I am using GitAhead GUI in Ubuntu 20.04. The font size is too small for me. Is there an option to zoom in all fonts in the entire GUI?

I found an option to set front size for the editor but not for the entire GUI.